# Using asynchronous load of the MediaNet ad script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to change the MediaNet ad script from the original, which is posted below to the one I found on one of the websites that recommends it for better page load performance.

I have done everything that was recommended, but still getting an error in console.

### Original Script

```
<script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
                medianet_width='300';
                medianet_height= '600';
                medianet_crid='#########';
                medianet_versionId = "######";
                (function() {
                    var isSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
                    var mnSrc = (isSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//contextual.media.net/nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9' + (isSSL ? '&https=1' : '');
                    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" id="mNSC" src="' + mnSrc + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
                })();
</script>
```

to the following:

### Script I am planning to use

```
<script>
    window._mNHandle = window._mNHandle || {};
    window._mNHandle.queue = window._mNHandle.queue || [];
    medianet_versionId = "######";
    (function() {
        var sct = document.createElement("script"),
            sctHl = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            isSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
        sct.type = "text/javascript";
        sct.src = (isSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//contextual.media.net/nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9' + (isSSL ? '&https=1' : '')+'';
        sct.async = "async";
        sctHl.parentNode.insertBefore(sct, sctHl);
    })();
</script>
<div id="#########" style="width:300px;height:600px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {window._mNHandle.queue.push(function () { window._mNDetails.loadTag("#########", "300x600", "#########"); }); }
        catch (error) {}
    </script>
</div>
```

### The Error I get

```
'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
s @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:3
h @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:3
l.execSafe @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:1
F @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:1
dt @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:1
bootstrap @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:3
se @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:3
l.execSafe @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:1
F @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:1
X @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:1
(anonymous) @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:3
(anonymous) @ nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9&https=1:3
```

Any thoughts or recommendations please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PostScribe to get around this error.

https://github.com/krux/postscribe

Comment: Thanks for this, looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake:

apparently I was supposed to use the following:

```
//contextual.media.net/dmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9
```

instead of

```
//contextual.media.net/nmedianet.js?cid=99CC99CC9
```

As you can guess, these are two different scripts and they perform different operations.

I hope that this can be helpful to someone like me